# What monitoring tools are available to monitor the load testing being done by IBM rational performance tester?

Tags: performance, load-testing, rpt

I am doing the load testing by using IBM rational performance tester on an application. I want to monitor the various resources like servers, middleware, networking etc. during the load testing in order to pinpoint the bottleneck. What monitoring tools I can use with IBM rational performance tester?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [Using IBM Rational Performance Tester: Resource monitoring Part 1, Reporting and scheduling](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0417_patel/)

> There are three resource monitoring data collectors provided in Rational Performance Tester:
>
> - Windows™ Performance Monitor for Microsoft® Windows® systems
> - rstatd for Linux®/UNIX® systems
> - IBM Tivoli® Monitoring (ITM) for monitoring a variety of platforms

so Rational Performance Tester seem to be having everything you need.

Also I believe you can use any standalone tool or service, see i.e.:

- [Top 10 Monitoring Tools that Every DevOps Needs](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-10-monitoring-tools-every-devops-needs)
- [40 Application Performance Management Tools](https://blog.profitbricks.com/application-performance-management-tools/)